# iPad, position:fixed, right:0;

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

On my webpage I currently have a sliding tab on the right hand side, with the fixed position  attribute applied to it and a negative right position to hide a part of it...

```
.element {
    position:fixed; 
    right:-200px; 
    width:300px; 
    background:red; 
    height:200px;
}
```

On the iPad however, I cannot get the element to remain fixed nor -200px off right, I've read somewhere that you cant use fixed as an attribute on mobile devices as due to the viewport being small it may hide certain things on the page, When the page loads and the ipad is held in portrait position though my element tends to load about 200px IN from the right, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an absolute position on your element. Position fixed isn't supported I believe.

```
.element {
    position:absolute; 
    right:-200px; 
    width:300px; 
    background:red; 
    height:200px;
}
```